# Top command to show the %cpu in descending order

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I would like to have the cpu percentage in decending order. When I give the command :

```
top -bn 1 | grep "^ " | awk '{ printf("%-8s  %-8s \n", $2, $9); }' | head -8
```

It shows processes which are not the top most using CPU.

Comment: This question should probably be migrated to [linux.se]

Answer (score 37):

Run top as a process (I'm using Ubuntu 14.04)

```
top
```

Once in top...

P <- Sort by CPU usage

M <- Sort by MEM usage

z <- Add cool visual colors

x <- Highlight column you are currently sorting by

Comment: The user wants this on the command line, not as an interactive process.

Comment: Even though the original question was for starting TOP from the command line with CPU sorted in descending order, I still found this useful for my use case. I run a RealVNC session, connecting to an Ubuntu desktop, on an Android tablet then start a full screen terminal session. Then I just type TOP and P and I have a separate display that gives me the current processes sorted by CPU.  Thanks.

Comment: This helped me a lot and a lot more often than I ... want to admit.

Answer (score 1):

In your command, you have

```
grep "^ "
```

which filters out lines that do not start with a space.

With this, you're filtering out processes that have PIDs longer than 4 characters, since the `top` command left pads the PIDs to 5 characters.

Use `grep "^[0-9 ]"` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try top with the -u flag: `top -u`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following :

```
top -o +%CPU
```